# Setting array value in struct sets a different field in struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a piece of code as follows, and when the line with comment (//error here) executes, it sets the status variable instead of the element in the array.

I moved the int status element above the array_name element in the struct definition and that seemed to have fixed it, I suspect that I am changing a pointer and am missing some parenthesis, but i am not sure why this was happening.

```
#define MAX_NUM 20
typedef struct FOO_T {
    bool abc;
    int id;
    int array_name[MAX_NUM];
    int counter;
    int status;
    SYSTEMTIME timestamp;

    struct FOO_T *next;
}

if (curr->array_name[code] == 0 )
{
    curr->counter++;
    curr->array_name[code] =  curr->counter; //error here
}
```

I also initialize the whole struct in a different function, part of that function is this:

```
thing->id = 0;
for (i = 0; i < MAX_NUM; i++) thing->array_name[i] = 0;
thing->counter = 0;
thing->status = 0;
```

Comment: maybe code is > then MAX_NUM? You just manged to copy not enough code...

Comment: I added to code above but it was already in my code #define MAX_NUM 20

Comment: @rene - It will also break if code == MAX_NUM

Comment: Also, use `memset`, `calloc` or `= {0}` to initialise, depending on how you're creating the struture.

Comment: @OrangeDog that is true. But for a noob (maybe rusty is better described) on C you have to admit that I was close...

Answer (score 3):

You should check that `code` is less than `MAX_NUM`.

In your particular case `code` is probably `MAX_NUM + 1`